# What is the fastest way to send files of any size and format to Hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I build web application for data analysis with Angular 6 frontend, Django 1.11 backend and Hadoop. I need to send files of any size and format in the fastest possible way to Hadoop. I would like to support both private users and the companies. I wonder what is the fastest way to send files of any size and format to Hadoop?

My solution:

```
    file = request.FILES['file']

    path = default_storage.save(str(file), ContentFile(file.read()))

    os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, path)

    command = 'hadoop fs -put ' + str(file) + ' /user/' + str(user_name) + '/' + str(file)

    os.system(command)

    command = 'rm -r ' + str(file)

    os.system(command)
```

Answer (score 1):

Hadoop FS put command will use hdfs/webhdfs, but the overhead of starting up a process for even the smallest file will make this operation hurt. I would have a look at using `hadoop copyfromlocal` with as many source files and 1-2 threads for each core.

For anyone having trouble with multiGB files; `hadoop fs -appendToFile` should let you build up a larger file from local parts, though it doesn't support any range in its command line (which it could, really). And there's work going on in the latest versions of Hadoop trunk for a better multipart upload API for HDFS and the object stores designed for parallel uploads of blocks with a final merge at the end.

Answer (score 0):

The only way that'll allow *any size* is to follow the HDFS RPC write protocol. E.g. `hdfs dfs -put`

Otherwise, webhdfs or NFS gateway will probably timeout for large files (over a few GB).

If you're not using HDFS, then use the respective libraries for your storage. Azure or S3, for example

---

A better solution than uploading files would be use some RDMBS, or Cassandra, for your analytics, and then use Sqoop, or Spark to export that data into Hadoop in a parallel fashion

Comment: I am going to create something like dropbox with data analysis. At the moment I transfer files from Angular 6 frontend to my Django 1.11 backend and then I send these files to Hadoop using Webhdfs. It works well with small files but uploading large files is a problem. The first of the problems is what you mentioned -  gateway will probably timeout for large files (over a few GB). Furthermore I store files in RAM so when I will be sending huge files it may be a problem.

Comment: I could also store them locally but the problem with timeout still exists. I tried also redirecting request from Angular frontend to Hadoop but this solution is also based on REST. So you suggest to store files for instance in blob format in a database and then transfer them to Hadoop?

Comment: What do you think about my solution added to the question? I use `HDFS RPC` what seems to be the only option. Furthermore the files are stored locally so there will be no overflow of the ram's memory.

Comment: The only downside with that approach is that it requires Java and the Hadoop XML files. So, if your server side application is not already Java based, or has no Java installed, then it's not portable to run it anywhere you want (if you care about that). You're not required to use `hdfs dfs` commands, but you would otherwise have to figure out the correct RPC binary packets to send to the namenode / datanodes. There are also python libraries such as PyArrow or pyhdfs that seem to be working on HDFS commands

Comment: Basically, looks like you're recreating HUE. Also a Django app that supports uploads to HDFS, but via WebHDFS

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Sqoop import you can try with the performance improvement parameters like mentioned below:
1. --fetch-size number
2. --direct 
3. --split-by
4. -m count
5. Boundary query
in sqoop tool